# How to create an Eclipse plugin

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

i need a complete tutorial about Eclipse plugin.
My plugin has not a graphical interface, but i need to use his function insiede another plugin or java app.
 I use eclipse ONLY to load this plugin, but must work in eclipse.
It should be easy, but i don't know how to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I often found Lars Vogel's tutorials really useful and simple. [This](http://www.vogella.de/articles/EclipsePlugIn/article.html) tutorial may be a good start point but be sure to check out the [complete list](http://www.vogella.de/eclipse.html) too.

Answer (score 1):

Very well designed wizards are available in eclipse itself. You just say new->plug-in project, and then after going through the wizard steps you can choose from templates like "plugin with popup menu, or "hello world" and so on. So the answer is simply use wizard.

Answer (score 0):

Both of the older answers are good.  Eclipse now has a "cheat sheet" that helps with plugin development.  In Eclipse, click Help -> Search, and search for “Creating an Eclipse Plug-in".  Among the results here is a “Creating an Eclipse Plug-in" cheat sheet.

[image: "]

Clicking this starts a cheat sheet (wizard) in the UI.  I found it very easy to use.  The little question marks on the right side of the cheat sheet give additional helpful information.

[image]